# Technology stack for scalable instant messaging application

Tags: xmpp, scalability, messenger

I would like to develop a massive scalable instant messaging cross platform application.I am starting from scratch.
Which is the best technology stack for this purpose.I had heard about ejabber xmpp etc.I would like to know which is the best programming language for the backend and also which is the reliable protocol(tcp/ip or rest)?
Can anyone help me?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is many possible options. If you want a basic chat, you can definitely build you own protocol based on low-level transport.

However, if you think your chat will be or can evolve to a full feature chat application, using XMPP is the way to go. It will avoid you to reinvent the wheel and leverage many advanced features available in the protocol.

There is many libraries available to help you get started and a server like ejabberd is indeed massively scalable.